# How can I geocode using the components parameter with the Google Maps Javascript API v3?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I am trying to use Google's geocoder to find a country by its ISO code. This is straight forward and reliable if I pass the components parameter (i.e. components=country:US). However, I've read through the docs and it looks like the Maps Javascript API v3 does not support this parameter. Since Google's geocoder no longer supports JSONP, I can't just use ajax.

Is there any way to specify components in the JS API or is there a workaround I'm not thinking of?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can just have a look on this post: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989653/how-to-prevent-google-geocoder-from-returning-results-from-other-countrys][1], it works for me :).


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989653/how-to-prevent-google-geocoder-from-returning-results-from-other-countrys

Answer (score 0):

It works for me when I use the ISO-code as `address`-property and additionally as `region`-property for the request.

Comment: It may work to use the ISO in region and address sometimes but not always. Sometimes the country with that ISO is not even returned by the geocoder. For example AL is the ISO for Albania but http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?region=AL&address=AL&sensor=false returns only Alabama

Comment: Region doesnt use ISO 3166-1, it uses "country code top-level domain (ccTLD)", which is a similar list but not exactly the same. Also, that Albania link does now return Albania, so maybe that was just a bug at the time. The country codes used for components is ISO 3166-1 though.

Answer (score 0):

I've begrudgingly gone ahead and hard-coded a mapping from ISO to country name. Makes me a little sick but you gotta do what you gotta do...