# not getting correct location on map by zipcode using google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google map. I want to search for ATM,bank,hospital many more on map by zip code. Current code shows all but for some zip codes it's not showing correct location . 
I am using following library 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places.

```
 var address=""+zaddress+"";

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      .
      .
      .
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try concatenating the country at the end of address string: `address + ", Brazil"` , for example (see [How to prevent google geocoder from returning results from other countries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989653/how-to-prevent-google-geocoder-from-returning-results-from-other-countries)). Also, there is the `components=country:[COUNTRY CODE]` property you could try.

Comment: but how do i get country from current user location

Comment: If you are thinking on the whole world as your scope would be easier if the user provides the country.